# JMeter - what's the usage of __logn function?

Tags: jmeter

JMeter have great functions but I don't understand why [__logn](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__logn) function exists? It does the same (less than) as `__log` function.

Is there a special case for using it? (also `logn` can be confused with complexity)

[image: a]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> The [logn](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__logn) function logs a message, and returns the empty string

The only difference between them is that:

- `__log()` function prints message to the *jmeter.log* file **and returns the generated message**
- `__logn()` function **just** prints message to the *jmeter.log* file (returns **nothing**

Demo:

[image: JMeter logn function]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) for comprehensive information on JMeter functions.